# Помогите найти простую ошибку (вылетает)

Tags: c

Вылетает прога, помогите найти ошибку пожалуйста.
Если что, программа должна устанавливать, является ли многоугольник выпуклым.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
int main(void)
{
    int k=0,polozh=0,otric=0,nevyp=0,i,j,n;
    int *a;
    FILE *pfile;
    pfile=fopen("C:/MinGW/progi/tochki.txt","r");
    if(pfile==NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found\n");
        return -1;
    }
    while(fscanf(pfile,"%d",&n)==1)
    {
        k++;
    }
    fclose(pfile);
    pfile=fopen("C:/MinGW/progi/tochki.txt","r");
    if(pfile==NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found\n");
        return -1;
    }
    a=(int*)malloc(k*sizeof(int));
    k=0;
    while(fscanf(pfile,"%d",&n)==1)
    {
        a[k]=n;
        k++;
    }
    for(j=0;j<k-3;j=j+2)
    {
        for(i=0;i<k-1;i=i+2)
        {
            if(((a[i]-a[j+2])*(a[j+3]-a[j+1])-(a[i+1]-a[j+3])*(a[j+2]-a[j]))/((a[j+2]-a[j])*(a[j+3]-a[j+1]))>=0)
                polozh=1;
            if(((a[i]-a[j+2])*(a[j+3]-a[j+1])-(a[i+1]-a[j+3])*(a[j+2]-a[j]))/((a[j+2]-a[j])*(a[j+3]-a[j+1]))<0)
                otric=1;
        }
        if((polozh==1)&&(otric==1))
            nevyp=1;
    }
    if(nevyp==1)
        printf("Nevypukliy ");
    else printf("Vypukliy ");
    fclose(pfile);
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Отладчиком посмотрите где вылетает

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте дополнительную проверку. 
Если у вас `a[j+2]` и `a[j]` окажутся равны, или `a[j+3]` и `a[j+1]` окажутся равны, то это приведет к делению на ноль.